# What are the best practices of writing google tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am writing tests for a large product which include about **2000** c++ classes. There are 5 projects in a solution of main product. I have made a separate solution for writing tests and added the include and lib directories of the main projects in it. In my unit testing project **(in visual studio**), I have made one main class which have the following code

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"   
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  return 0;
}
```

Other than this, I have made five filters for each project of the main product solution. Each filter contains the test classes for the classes in a project of main product solution. In each test class, there is a fixture that SetUp and TearDown pointer variables and in cpp files, I am registering that fixture class and perform test operation as follow

```
TEST_F(FixtureClassName, testFunction) 
{
    // testing logic and asserts    
}
// more test cases
```

For the common functionality that has to be used by all test classes, I have made utility classes in my test project and when any class need that functionality, it just call the functions written in those utility classes.

I have written tests for about 20 classes and when I run my tests code, it runs the tests written in all the classes (in all filters). 
I want to ask, how can I improve the structure of it further?

Is there a way that I **run** the tests of just **one** class fixture at a time?

And should my testing project be in the main product solution or is it a right way that I have made a separate solution for it?

I have read a discussion in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googletestframework/qRM_x_DZFTA) link, that shows we have to make separate executable for each class when we start writing tests. How can I make separate executable and is it a better way?

Comment: You can filter which tests to run with the `--gtest_filter` command line argument - are you having some particular problem running just one of your tests with that ?

Comment: Can you explain further, what should I write in command line arguments. I have written --gtest_filter and it shows some details in cmd window. If I want to run tests of test fixture named  "Calculator", what should I write in command line argument?

Comment: likely --gtest_filter=Calculator.* or --gtest_filter=*Calculator , but I think the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Running_a_Subset_of_the_Tests) would be of better help. That page also gives you a lot of hints on how to write and name your tests.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is, if your production code is made of 5 projects, at first glance it makes sense to have 5 tests projects, so that each project can be tested in isolation (basic separation of concern).

If one project have dependencies on some classes of other projects, that's the typical case where you would implement Mock Classes to be able to test.

So 5 test executables ( and certainly not 2000 ? one for each class ? I doubt that it makes any sense. )

What makes sense is to have one class test Fixture for each of production class. But that's the first naïve implementation, because there is at least the two following cases to consider

- if you have Object Oriented classes (parent / childs), you might want
  to have Parameterized tests
- if you have Templated classes, you probably want to have Templated
  tests (Typed Tests)

For the next question,
to have them in the same solution or in a separate solution is up to you.

Same solution pro :

- if changes are made in the production code that break APIs
  compatibility, the associated test project won't compile so it's
  quicker to have them running

Same solution cons :

- Extra compile time, larger solution.

Finally, you can decide what test you run with the gtest_filter as mentioned in comments by @nos. But this is not related to how you should architecture those tests.